# Featured product is going off from home page when cache is enabled

Tags: magento-1.7, featured-product

In my current project the featured products are not showing on home page until i am not disabling the cache. When i disabled the cache featured products is showing and after enabling again it is not showing.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey maybe turning of the caching for this block would solve that issue if thats the only block which is not working when using caching.
See link below, I use the same strategy and it works perfect for me
http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-turn-off-cache-for-an-individual-block-in-magento/

Comment: If that is the case then can you let me know folder structure where i need to add for featured products widget. @Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Yes got it by changing the cache_lifetime from 7200 to null in dynamicproducts.php page.

$this->addData(array(
                'cache_lifetime'    => null,
                'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG)
            ));